# Regading C++ pointers and functions

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have a code in C++.

```
int* func(int n) {
    int* v= &n;
    return v;
}
int main()
{
    int* c = func(5);
    int* k = func(9);
    cout<<*c;
}
```

This code returns a 9 instead of a 5.
However, when I change the func to

```
int* func(int n) {
    int* v= new int(n);
    return v;
}
```

This returns a 5 as expected. Is there a reason why the 1st one doesn't work but the 2nd one does?

Comment: The variable `n` is a ***local*** variable, whose life-time ends when the function returns. Returning a pointer to it would make no sense as the pointer would become immediately invalid.

Comment: You are returning the address of a function parameter which is a temporary. That's Undefined Behavior. (I.e. whatever you got is unreliable.)

Comment: The second variant have another problem (with how you currently use the function): A memory leak. You allocate memory with `new` but you never `delete` it.

Answer (score 1):

`func` is returning a pointer to parameter `n`. Note that `n` is declared as pass-by-value, it'll be destroyed when the function ends. Then the returned pointer is always dangling, dereference on it leads to [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

The 2nd code snippet doesn't have such issue. `func` is returning a pointer `new`ed in function body, it's valid even after function ends. (BTW the returned pointer has to be `delete`ed somewhere to avoid memory leak.)